# MySQL left join missing results

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to see if I have some unused SIP numbers, so I have a list of numbers in the table *tmp_numbers*

```
0203XXXXX00
0203XXXXX01
0203XXXXX02
0203XXXXX03
...
```

The query I use is:

```
SELECT 
 n.number,
 COUNT(c.did) AS count

FROM tmp_numbers n

LEFT JOIN cdr c
 ON n.number = c.did 

WHERE c.calldate >= '2017-01-01'

GROUP BY n.number
ORDER BY n.number
```

I get results from the above query, but it omits numbers it can't match on *c.did*.

I was under the impression that a LEFT JOIN would match/display everything on left table (tmp_numbers), regardless if there is a value on the right side (so it will show NULL?)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the  `where` condition in the `left join`. Otherwise it turns implicitly into an `inner join`  because conditions in the `where` clause filter on all data and if `calldate` is NULL then the condition is FALSE

```
LEFT JOIN cdr c ON n.number = c.did 
               AND c.calldate >= '2017-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on a column from the `JOINED` table which maybe `null` if there is no corresponding entry, so change the `WHERE` condition from:

`WHERE c.calldate >= '2017-01-01'`

to

`WHERE c.calldate >= '2017-01-01' OR c.did IS NULL`